# How to view timeline for HTTP connect tunnels in Fiddler?

Tags: https, fiddler, timeline, http-tunneling

I have set the decrypt HTTPS option in the Fiddler2 and so it shows the timeline for HTTPS requests.

But not able to see timeline of HTTP connect tunnel requests. Any way to enable this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's not much of a "timeline" to show for a CONNECT tunnel itself. Are you looking to see the timings of the HTTPS requests *inside* the tunnel? If so, enable HTTPS Decryption in Fiddler's options, and select the HTTPS requests rather than the tunnel itself.